# trying to get property of non-object (view In Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Fellow Coders,

I have been trying to post the authenticated user to the index view for an hour registration application i'm trying to implement. The problem is, I dd()'d the variable and the username did come out of it. But when I try to call the username in the view. It gives me the error posted in the title..

```
        $authenticated = Sentinel::getUser()->first_name;
    //dd($authenticated);

    return view('hoursregistrations.index', compact('authenticated'));
```

and the view call

```
Hoursregistrations List of {{ $authenticated->first_name }}
```

I would love to recieve any tips and or help in this situation

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

I made a rookie mistake it seems,

I should have changed

```
$authenticated = Sentinel::getUser()->first_name;
```

to

```
$authenticated = Sentinel::getUser();
```

And then I could use that object to get the username of the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `$authenticated` its your first name, and you call first_name on first_name , you should use in view only `{{ $authenticated }}`.